# Hessian of function at many points

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

If

```
f:= x^3 + 2yz + 5 x^2z
```

is a function and if `{2,0,1},{3,9,2},{8,5,6},{1,1,7}` are points.
I would like a Hessian of `f` with the four points together.

I did that with the first point like:

```
hessian[x_, y_, z_] = Function[{f}, D[f, {{x, y, z}}, {{x, y, z}}] ]; 
f[x_, y_, z_] :=  x^3 + 2yz + 5 x^2z;
hessian[x, y, z][f[x, y, z]]//FullSimplify
%/.{x->2,y->0,z->1}
```

So, I need to apply Hessian of `f` at all the points at the same time. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3):

```
hessianF[x_,y_,z_] = hessian[x, y, z][f[x, y, z]]//FullSimplify;

hessianF @@@ {{2,0,1},{3,9,2},{8,5,6},{1,1,7}}
```

Comment: No open Mathematica at hand currently, but I believe this should do the tricj.